# embedding image inside as3 using Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, embedded-resource

I'm using Flash Pro, CS6 on the Mac.

I've got this class

```
package classes
{
    public class AssetEmbeds_1x
    {
        //kid
        [Embed(source = '../graphics/Player_Graphics.swf')]
        public static const playerG:Class;
    }
}
```

Which is a swf which contains an exported (on 1st frame) movieclip called kidCharacter. I'm trying to access that kidCharacter movieclip from another class, and I'm not able to do that.

I've tried this...

```
var textureClass:Class = AssetEmbeds_1x;
var newClass = textureClass['playerG'];

myGraphic = newClass['kidCharacter'];
```

But it's not working, myGraphic (which is a movieclip) is always null. I'm not sure if it's even embedding anything.

Comment: Try removing the `..` e.g. `[Embed(source = '/graphics/Player_Graphics.swf')]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var player:MovieClip = new AssetsEmbeds_1x.playerG();
var kid:MovieClip = player.root.kidCharacter;
```

Comment: Tried that, gave me the error "Property kidCharacter not found on classes.AssetEmbeds_1x_playerG"

Comment: Gave me the error "1119: Access of possibly undefined property kidCharacter through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObject."

Comment: Try this: `var kid:MovieClip = MovieClip(player.root).kidCharacter;`

Comment: gives error because root = null, it is loading the .swf though, I just can't seem to access any of it's content.